# We cannot get the native access to contacts list using the cordova plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

We are trying to get native access to a phone contacts list using the cordova-plugin-contacts (both ios/android testing devices, and emulators tried!).

We've tried all the threads around the net we can find, and various methods/tutorials to try and do it, but nothing seems to work. We just get blank screens as the .ts fails. We've tried from simple projects, and lost at this point! We understand that cordova no longer support the code due to security concerns, but are aware that people are still able to use the code somehow.

Our structure:
Ionic CLI 4.12.0

Angular CLI 7.3.6

Cordova CLI 9.0.0

NodeJS 11.12.0

Others tried:
npm install @ionic-native/contacts

In providers:

```
import { Contacts } from '@ionic-native/contacts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    Contacts
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Contact</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of contactsFound">

        <h3 style="padding-top: 5rem;">{{contact?.displayName}}</h3>

        <!--Recorro el numero de cada contacto-->
        <p *ngFor="let num of contact?.phoneNumbers">
          {{num.value}}
        </p>

    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

In the .ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';

//Importo la libreria de contactos...
import { Contacts, ContactFieldType, IContactFindOptions} from "@ionic-native/contacts";

//Definimos el selector y los templates y estilos...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.page.html'
})

//Clase Principal de la pagina de Contactos...
export class ContactPage {

  ourtype: ContactFieldType[] = ["displayName"];
  contactsFound = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private contacts: Contacts){
    this.search('');
  }

  //Metodo para buscar un contacto con el metodo find();
  search(q){

    const option: IContactFindOptions = {
      filter: q
    }

    this.contacts.find(this.ourtype, option).then(cont => {
      this.contactsFound = cont
    })
  }

}
```

We've tried adding alerts, but all fail in the code... it just dies!

Comment: Here's our class now @Rahul

export class ContactPage{

ourtype: ContactFieldType[] = ["displayName"];
contactsFound = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private contact: Contacts, private platform: Platform){

const option: ContactFindOptions = {
  filter: ""
}

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  alert("INSIDE READY")
  this.contact.find(this.ourtype, option).then((cont) => {
    alert("INSIDE FIND");
    this.contactsFound = cont;
  })
});
}

}

Answer (score 0):

HI Matt listen to platform ready event, once it's triggered then only you can access native features like contacts camera etc..

eg:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    // access contact here  contact.find call 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, we now get alerts working just before the contact.find method, but still nothing from that point onwards.

Comment: Do we need the enterprise version of ionic to access this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Contacts, ContactFieldType, IContactFindOptions} from "@ionic-native/contacts";
```

Im not able to use Contacts class in constructor as it is deprecated. Please suggest alternative. I tried using "dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers", `navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers` shows empty object `{}`. There is no `list()` function in `navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers` object.